# Sending message to all my contacts on whatsapp using whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, whatsapi

Hi I´m currently doing a code to send a message to all my contacts, I've been able to send a message to only one contact, do anyone know a way to automatize this, for example send a message to my first 5 contacts, or all my contacts?

Here is my code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    client.getChats().then((chats)=>{
        const myGroup=chats.find(
            (chat)=>chat.name==="Whatsapp automation"
        );
        client.sendMessage(
            myGroup.id._serialized,
            "This is an automated message"
            );
    });
});
```

If someone could me, I will be too grateful, thanks so much for your attention

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows, loop through your chat objects

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  const message = 'your message here';
  sendToChats(message);
});

async function sendToChats(m){
  const mychats = await client.getChats();
  for(chat of mychats){
    chat.sendMessage(m);
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).